# Error in VoteforSizeandOrientation and Cam capture EMGUCV C#

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I'm new to programming with *EMGU CV* and *OpenCV* so I may have made some silly mistakes. I'm writing a program to detect a specific logo of a company of a set of boxes with different logos in a warehouse. The camera will be top down orientated. I have started off simple with the example provided in the *EMGU CV* wiki and I am trying to use a BRIEF descriptor with a FAST Extractor since SURF is too slow. I am getting two errors. The first one is this.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

It occurs in this line of code

```
        observerframe  = capture.QueryGrayFrame();
```

The next error is this

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

and it occurs in this line of code

```
    nonZeroCount = Features2DToolbox.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(ObjectKeypoints, SceneKeypoints, indices, mask, 1.5, 20);
```

My full code is provided below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;


using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Features2D;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
namespace train
{
    public partial class Detectingwindow : Form
    {
        public Bitmap testobject;
        public Capture capture;
        public Image<Gray, Byte> observerframe;
        bool captureinprogress;
        bool detect = false;
        
        public Detectingwindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void matcher_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void camcapture(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            capture = new Capture(); 
            observerframe  = capture.QueryGrayFrame();

            if (observerframe != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, Byte> objectbnw = new Image<Gray, byte>(testobject);
                Image<Bgr, Byte> output = Draw(objectbnw, observerframe);
                imageBox1.Image = output;
            }
            return;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region if capture is not created, create it now
            if (capture == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    capture = new Capture();
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
                }
            }
            #endregion

            if (capture != null)
            {
                if (captureinprogress)
                {  //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text
                    // "Start" for resuming capture
                    button1.Text = "Restart"; 
                    Application.Idle -= camcapture;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button
                    // Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
                    button1.Text = "Pause";
                    Application.Idle += camcapture;
                    
                    
                }

                captureinprogress = !captureinprogress;
            }
        }
        public static Image<Bgr, Byte> Draw(Image<Gray, Byte> testobject, Image<Gray, byte> scene)
        {
            
                Image<Bgr, Byte> Draw;
                HomographyMatrix H = null;
                FastDetector detector = new FastDetector(10, true);
                VectorOfKeyPoint ObjectKeypoints, SceneKeypoints;
                Matrix<int> indices;
               // Freak extractor = new Freak(true, true, 22.0f, 4);
               BriefDescriptorExtractor extractor = new BriefDescriptorExtractor();
                Matrix<byte> mask;


                ObjectKeypoints = detector.DetectKeyPointsRaw(testobject, null);
                Matrix<Byte> ObjectDescriptors = extractor.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(testobject, null, ObjectKeypoints);

                SceneKeypoints = detector.DetectKeyPointsRaw(scene, null);
                Matrix<Byte> SceneDescriptors = extractor.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(scene, null, SceneKeypoints);

                BruteForceMatcher<Byte> matcher = new BruteForceMatcher<byte>(DistanceType.Hamming);
                matcher.Add(SceneDescriptors);

                indices = new Matrix<int>(SceneDescriptors.Rows, 2);
                using (Matrix<float> dist = new Matrix<float>(SceneDescriptors.Rows, 2))
                {
                    matcher.KnnMatch(SceneDescriptors, indices, dist, 2, null);
                    mask = new Matrix<byte>(dist.Rows, 1);
                    mask.SetValue(255);
                    Features2DToolbox.VoteForUniqueness(dist, 0.8, mask);
                }

                int nonZeroCount = CvInvoke.cvCountNonZero(mask);

                if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
                {
                    nonZeroCount = Features2DToolbox.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(ObjectKeypoints, SceneKeypoints, indices, mask, 1.5, 20);
                    if (nonZeroCount <= 4)
                    {
                        H = Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(ObjectKeypoints, SceneKeypoints, indices, mask, 2);
                    }
                }

                Draw = Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(testobject, ObjectKeypoints, scene, SceneKeypoints, indices, new Bgr(255, 255, 255), new Bgr(255, 255, 255), mask, Features2DToolbox.KeypointDrawType.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
                if (H != null)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = testobject.ROI;
                    PointF[] pts = new PointF[] {
         new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Bottom),
         new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
         new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Top),
         new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Top)};
                    H.ProjectPoints(pts);
                    Draw.DrawPolyline(Array.ConvertAll<PointF, Point>(pts, Point.Round), true, new Bgr(Color.Red), 5);
                }
                return Draw;
           
            
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Sorry about not properly correcting indentations etc. or commenting. Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks